# Sharing location in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am developing an iOS app using the Swift language and I have to check location access in the splash screen.
How can I push to another view controller after the user accepts sharing location, otherwise show following alert to inform the user?

> Please enable GPS in the Settings app

In splashScreen I used this code:

```
let LocationMgr = LocationSingleton.sharedInstance //location
let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

switch status {
// 1
case .notDetermined:
    LocationMgr.locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    break
// 2
case .denied, .restricted:
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Location Services disabled", message: "Please enable Location Services in Settings", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okAction)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    break
case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
    //I want to push to another view 
    break
}

// 4
LocationMgr.delegate = self
LocationMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
```

How do I check if location services are enabled after the user selects (`authorizedAlways`, `authorizedWhenInUse`) and then push to another view?

Comment: Not related to the issue but this is Swift: No `break` statements in `switch` cases which have a body.

Answer (score 0):

**if using Storyboard**

In the Storyboard create a Segue between your initial Screen and the next screen. Right-click and Drag from controller icon to the next Screen. and

[image: create Segue]

And enter an Identifier:

[image]

Then in your switch statement:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNextScreen", sender: nil)
```